# Comentário em multiplas linhas e error de identação Python

Tags: python, syntax-error, indentação

Estava escrevendo meu código e precisava bloquear algumas linhas de código. Como são várias, resolvi utilizar as 3 aspas para bloquear uma parte do código. [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Entretanto, quando rodo o código ele apresenta erro de indentação. Alguem sabe o que tenho feito de errado?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já percebi que quando coloco # Não acontece esse erro de indentação.

Comment: a cima do def abrirjanela2 esta identado, ai vem a string não identada, e depois uma função identada, vai dar erro mesmo, vc deve colocar a cotagem identada tambem

Comment: O que seria cotagem??

Comment: é oq faz o texto ser uma string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em Python a única coisa feita para comentar código é o `#` , o que você está fazendo usando `'''` é apenas um String Literal, ou seja, um `docstring`, o mesmo serve para comentar, **porém deve também estar identado**, como no exemplo:

```
def funcao():

    '''
    comentários aqui
    '''
    print("vai printar")
```

Vale lembrar que isso serve para outras coisas também, por exemplo se você ir em uma IDE e digitar `help(funcao)`, o que iria ser mostrado seria:

```
'comentários aqui'
```

Eu praticamente traduzi essa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31955188/indent-and-comments-in-function-in-python) para você.